# Openxlsx in R Cell Merging and Centering content

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am using `openxlsx` in r to create excel files with certain formatting parameters.  The following is the reusable code:

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "TestSheet")
df <- mtcars
df$Car <- row.names(mtcars)
row.names(df) <- NULL
df <- df[,c(length(df), 1:length(df)-1)]

forTopTit <- createStyle(fontColour = "#ffffff", fgFill = "#F4D03F",halign = "center",wrapText = TRUE,valign = "center")
forColHdr <- createStyle(fontColour = "#ffffff", fgFill = "#4F81BD",halign = "center",wrapText = TRUE,valign = "center")
forDatStl <- createStyle(fontColour = "#ffffff", halign="center")

writeData(wb,"TestSheet", "THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE", startCol = 1,startRow = 1,colNames = FALSE, rowNames = TRUE,
          headerStyle = forTopTit,borders = "surrounding",borderStyle = "medium")

writeData(wb,"TestSheet", df, startCol = 1,startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE,rowNames = FALSE,
          headerStyle = forColHdr,borders='all',borderStyle = "thin")
mergeCells(wb, "TestSheet", cols=1:length(df), rows=1)
setColWidths(wb, "TestSheet", ignoreMergedCells = TRUE,cols = 1:ncol(df), widths = "auto")
openXL(wb)
```

I am facing two problems:

1. The title which I am trying to create in the first col first row  (which is a merged cell) is always left aligned and none of the color is getting applied.
2. I want to center the data from row 3 col 2, which I am not able to do.  I tried using the following code:

   addStyle(wb, "TestSheet", style=forDatStl, rows = 3:nrow(df), cols=3:length(df), gridExpand=TRUE)

The above kind of hides all the data points, though it still remains in the cell.  I am not able to see them but when I select the cell i could see it on the summary line above the sheet.  I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Libre Office Calc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your cells are "hidden" because you set the color `#ffffff`, which is white, and the background is white.

Use another color:

```
forDatStl <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000", halign="center")
```

To center the merged cells:

```
centerStyle <- createStyle(halign = "center")
mergeCells(wb, "TestSheet", cols=1:length(df), rows=1)
addStyle(wb, "TestSheet", centerStyle, rows = 1, cols = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks,  I did figured the font color issue...however, I could not get the text center aligned.  Thank you again

Comment: Do you know how to center an image using `openxlsx::InsertImage`?